# Casting a SelectedItem (object) to an individual dictionary entry

Tags: c#

How do I cast a selected item to that of type Dictionary

This is my object

```
private Dictionary<string, string> PickerItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();

 public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> PickerItemList
 {
        get => PickerItems.ToList();

 }
```

I would normally do this to get the selected item but How do I do that with key-value pair

```
var sourcearehouseObj = pickWarehouseSource.SelectedItem as ObjectType?
```

What should `ObjectType?` be, exactly. Should it be `KeyValuePair<string, string>`? Or something else?

Comment: whats' the data type of `pickWarehouseSource.SelectedItem`

Comment: What do you want to get exactly?

Comment: I take it that you want to turn a list of `KeyValuePair` to a Dictionary?

Comment: This is propably beyond casting. Co- or Contravariance might be close. And of course a good old "make a new collection and copy the contents with a loop" would always work. At the usual cost of extra work for the GC down the line.

Comment: Do you mean to convert the List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> back in to a dictionary? If so, you can use a Linq statement: PickerItems = PickerItemList.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with the following I simply needed to no the casting type.

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> selectedEntry = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)pickWarehouseSource.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: This has no relevance to the way you have worded the question

Comment: It actually does @AvinKavish

Comment: It does have relevance **now**, after my edit @rogue39nin. I agree with Avin - before my edit, your original question was **super unclear**.